# Powershell: Import-csv, rename all headers

Tags: powershell, header, rename, import-csv

In our company there are many users and many applications with restricted access and database with evidence of those accessess. I don´t have access to that database, but what I do have is automatically generated (once a day) csv file with all accessess of all my users. I want them to have a chance to check their access situation so i am writing a simple powershell script for this purpose.

CSV:

```
user;database1_dat;database2_dat;database3_dat
john;0;0;1
peter;1;0;1
```

I can do:

```
import-csv foo.csv | where {$_.user -eq $user}
```

But this will show me original ugly headres (with "_dat" suffix). Can I delete last four characters from every header which ends with "_dat", when i **can´t predict how many headers will be there tomorrow?**

I am aware of calculated property like:

```
Select-Object @{ expression={$_.database1_dat}; label='database1' }
```

but i have to know all column names for that, as far as I know.

Am I convicted to "overingeneer" it by separate function and build whole "calculated property expression" from scratch dynamically or is there a simple way i am missing?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that file `foo.csv` fits into memory as a whole, the following solution performs well:

- If you need a memory-throttled - but invariably much slower - solution, see [Santiago Squarzon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68441555/45375) or the alternative approach in the bottom section.

```sh
$headerRow, $dataRows = (Get-Content -Raw foo.csv) -split '\r?\n', 2

# You can pipe the result to `where {$_.user -eq $user}`
ConvertFrom-Csv ($headerRow -replace '_dat(?=;|$)'), $dataRows -Delimiter ';'
```

- [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) `-Raw` reads the entire file into memory, which is much faster than reading it line by line (the default).
- [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split)  `'\r?\n', 2` splits the resulting multi-line string into two: the header line and all remaining lines.

  - Regex `\r?\n` matches a newline (both a CRLF (`\r\n`) and a LF-only newline (`\n`))
  - `, 2` limits the number of tokens to return to `2`, meaning that splitting stops once the 1st token (the header row) has been found, and the remainder of the input string (comprising all data rows) is returned as-is as the last token.
  - Note the `$null` as the first target variable in the multi-assignment, which is used to discard the *empty* token that results from the separator regex matching at the very start of the string.
- `$headerRow -replace '_dat(?=;|$)'`

  - [`-replace`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) `'_dat(?=;|$)'` uses a regex to remove any `_dat` column-name suffixes (followed by a `;` or the end of the string); if substring `_dat` only ever occurs as a name *suffix* (not also *inside* names), you can simplify to `-replace '_dat'`
- [`ConvertFrom-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-csv) directly accepts *arrays* of strings, so the cleaned-up header row and the string with all data rows can be passed  as-is.

---

**Alternative solution: algorithmic renaming of an object's properties**:

Note: This solution is *slow*, but may be an option if you only extract a *few* objects from the CSV file.

As you note in the question, use of [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) with [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties) is not an option in your case, because you neither know the column names nor their number in advance.

However, you can use a [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) command in which you use `.psobject.Properties`, an [intrinsic member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members), for *reflection* on the input objects:

```sh
Import-Csv -Delimiter ';' foo.csv | where { $_.user -eq $user } | ForEach-Object {
  # Initialize an aux. ordered hashtable to store the renamed
  # property name-value pairs.
  $renamedProperties = [ordered] @{}
  # Process all properties of the input object and
  # add them with cleaned-up names to the hashtable.
  foreach ($prop in $_.psobject.Properties) {
    $renamedProperties[($prop.Name -replace '_dat(?=.|$)')] = $prop.Value
  }
  # Convert the aux. hashtable to a custom object and output it.
  [pscustomobject] $renamedProperties
}
```

Comment: Do you think this would be the best performing solution? I'm looking to implement something similar and the solution on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7.1#example-4--change-property-names-in-an-imported-object) is arguably much less efficient; so looking to see if this solution is the 'best' or if it would be even faster using .Where() and a few other tweaks

Comment: I was thinking `$headerRow, $dataRows = (Get-Content -ReadCount 0 foo.csv).Where({$_}, 'Split', 1)` but it doesn't seem any faster, but it does seem to have different output from `-split` or at least different than using -Raw.

Comment: @immobile2, if it's acceptable to get the rest of the file as a single, multi-line string, the first solution is the fastest I'm aware of. While `-ReadCount 0` speeds up things if you can process the resulting array _as a whole_, `.Where()` of necessity _enumerates_ the array again, and executing a script block (`{ ... }`) for each enumerated element is slow - you may as well do `$headerRow, $dataRows = Get-content foo.csv`, though you can speed that up significantly with `$headerRow, $dataRows = [IO.File]::ReadAllLines((Convert-Path foo.csv))`

Comment: Probably too long for a comment, let me know if you think a separate answer would be helpful for future searchers or not. I _finally_ grasped what your `-split` was truly doing, the fact that you're treating the 1st true row as the delimiter itself and then returning it is slick; but possibly more complicated than necessary or at least took longer for me to grasp what is actually happening. Consider this alternative: `$null, $headerRow, $dataRows = (gc -Raw foo.csv) -split '^', 3, 'multiline'` you can even streamline things a bit with `((gc -Raw foo.csv) -split '^', 3, 'multiline').Trim()`

Comment: @immobile2, yes, it was too complicated; the simplest solution is `-split '\r?\n', 2`, which also obviates the need for `$null` as the first receiving variable - this simplification is already part of the (recently updated) answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
$textInfo = (Get-Culture).TextInfo
$headers = (Get-Content .\test.csv | Select-Object -First 1).Split(';') |
ForEach-Object {
    $textInfo.ToTitleCase($_) -replace '_dat'
}

$user = 'peter'

Get-Content .\test.csv | Select-Object -Skip 1 |
ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';' -Header $headers |
Where-Object User -EQ $user
```

```
User  Database1 Database2 Database3
----  --------- --------- ---------
peter 1         0         1
```

Not super efficient but does the trick.

Comment: I have used mklement0`s solution at the end, but this is also perfectly valid solution for my problem.  I can use this approach in some future project. Thank you, really.